# Removing variable logic from controller, moving it to service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to move the logic for the variable `replacers` from the controller **PhraseListCtrl** in `controllers.js` to **CategoryService** in `services.js`.

The current setup (which works fine), is as follows:

**In controller.js**

```js
    function PhraseListCtrl($scope, $stateParams, CategoryService) {

      $scope.categoryId = $stateParams.categoryId;
      $scope.category = $stateParams.category;

      CategoryService.getCategoryDetail($scope.categoryId).then(function(dataResponse) {
        $scope.categoryDetail = dataResponse.data;

        var replacers = {
          '{{group}}': '<a class="button button-small button-outline button-positive button-side-padding">group</a>',
          '{{attribute}}': '<a class="button button-small button-outline button-assertive button-side-padding">attribute</a>',
          '{{factor}}': '<a class="button button-small button-outline button-assertive button-side-padding">factor</a>',
          '{{person}}': '<a class="button  button-small button-outline button-positive button-side-padding">person</a>'
        }

        console.log(replacers);

        $scope.categoryDetail.forEach(function(e) {
          Object.keys(replacers).forEach(function(key) {
            e['phrase_filter'] = e['phrase_filter'].replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), replacers[key]);
          })
        })

      });

    }
```

**In services.js**

```js
function CategoryService($http) {

        this.getCategoryList = function () {

            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category/',
            });

        }


        this.getCategoryDetail = function (categoryId) {

            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category/' + categoryId,
            });

        }

    }
```

---

However, when I move the logic around a bit, it I can't seem to access the variable `replacers` anymore.

**In controller.js**

```js
    function PhraseListCtrl($scope, $stateParams, CategoryService) {

      $scope.categoryId = $stateParams.categoryId;
      $scope.category = $stateParams.category;

      CategoryService.getCategoryDetail($scope.categoryId).then(function(dataResponse) {
        $scope.categoryDetail = dataResponse.data;

        var replacers = CategoryService.getCategoryFilter;

        console.log(replacers);

        $scope.categoryDetail.forEach(function(e) {
          Object.keys(replacers).forEach(function(key) {
            e['phrase_filter'] = e['phrase_filter'].replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), replacers[key]);
          })
        })

      });

    }
```

**In services.js**

```
function CategoryService($http) {

    this.getCategoryList = function () {

        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category/',
        });

    }


    this.getCategoryDetail = function (categoryId) {

        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category/' + categoryId,
        });

    }

    this.getCategoryFilter = function () {

        var replacers = [{
            '{{group}}' : '<a class="button button-small button-outline button-positive button-side-padding">group</a>',
            '{{attribute}}' : '<a class="button button-small button-outline button-assertive button-side-padding">attribute</a>',
            '{{factor}}' : '<a class="button button-small button-outline button-assertive button-side-padding">factor</a>',
            '{{person}}' : '<a class="button  button-small button-outline button-positive button-side-padding">person</a>'
        }]

        return replacers;

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the reference for the function in this line:

```
var replacers = CategoryService.getCategoryFilter;
```

You should call the function like this

```
var replacers = CategoryService.getCategoryFilter();
```

That should do it.

**Edit**

Also it happens that you are creating an array for the `replacers` in the service, but you want to access an object.